# How to print pandas horizontally?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to print the output of pandas dummies (One-Hot-Encoding) horizontally instead of vertically, when printed vertically the headers are very difficult to correctly match to their code, also when vertically printed there are more indexes than needed, and it takes several minutes to complete. I would like to print the output horizontally so the headers are above their coding, and so there is only one index. I have also tried assigning names to each item and printing them as a group, and that didn't really work the way I wanted it to, because it turned 6,392 lines of data into 140,666 lines. The code is down below.

```
Code:

df = pd.read_csv('Filename.txt')
df.columns = ['Date','b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6','b7','b8','b9','b10','b11','b12','b13','b14','b15','b16','b17','b18','b19','b20','b21','b22']
df = df.set_index('Date')
reversed_df = df.iloc[::-1]

n=5
print('Game')
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
print(reversed_df.drop(df.index[n:-n]),("\n"))

BallOne = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b1)
BallTwo = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b2)
BallThree = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b3)
BallFour = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b4)
BallFive = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b5)
BallSix = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b6)
BallSeven = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b7)
BallEight = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b8)
BallNine = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b9)
BallTen = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b10)
BallEleven = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b11)
BallTwelve = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b12)
BallThirteen = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b13)
BallFourteen = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b14)
BallFifteen = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b15)
BallSixteen = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b16)
BallSeventeen = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b17)
BallEightteen = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b18)
BallNineteen = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b19)
BallTwenty = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b20)
BallTwentyOne = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b21)
BallTwentyTwo = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b22)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
#(pd.concat([BallOne, BallTwo, BallThree, BallFour, BallFive, BallSix, BallSeven, BallEight, BallNine, BallTen, BallEleven, BallTwelve,     BallThirteen, BallFourteen, BallFifteen, BallSixteen, BallSeventeen, BallEightteen, BallNineteen, BallTwenty, BallTwentyOne, BallTwentyTwo], keys = ['K-B1', 'K-B2', 'K-B3', 'K-B4', 'K-B5', 'K-B6', 'K-B7', 'K-B8', 'K-B9', 'K-B10', 'K-B11', 'K-B12', 'K-B13', 'K-B14', 'K-B15', 'K-B16', 'K-B17', 'K-B18', 'K-B19', 'K-B20', 'K-B21', 'K-B22'], axis=1),("\n"))

p1 = (pd.concat([BallOne], keys = ['B1'], axis=1))
p2 = (pd.concat([BallTwo], keys = ['B2'], axis=1))
p3 = (pd.concat([BallThree], keys = ['B3'], axis=1))
p4 = (pd.concat([BallFour], keys = ['B4'], axis=1))
p5 = (pd.concat([BallFive], keys = ['B5'], axis=1))
p6 = (pd.concat([BallSix], keys = ['B6'], axis=1))
p7 = (pd.concat([BallSeven], keys = ['B7'], axis=1))
p8 = (pd.concat([BallEight], keys = ['B8'], axis=1))
p9 = (pd.concat([BallNine], keys = ['B9'], axis=1))
p10 = (pd.concat([BallTen], keys = ['B10'], axis=1))
p11 = (pd.concat([BallEleven], keys = ['B11'], axis=1))
p12 = (pd.concat([BallTwelve], keys = ['B12'], axis=1))
p13 = (pd.concat([BallThirteen], keys = ['B13'], axis=1))
p14 = (pd.concat([BallFourteen], keys = ['B14'], axis=1))
p15 = (pd.concat([BallFifteen], keys = ['B15'], axis=1))
p16 = (pd.concat([BallSixteen], keys = ['B16'], axis=1))
p17 = (pd.concat([BallSeventeen], keys = ['B17'], axis=1))
p18 = (pd.concat([BallEightteen], keys = ['B18'], axis=1))
p19 = (pd.concat([BallNineteen], keys = ['B19'], axis=1))
p20 = (pd.concat([BallTwenty], keys = ['B20'], axis=1))
p21 = (pd.concat([BallTwentyOne], keys = ['B21'], axis=1))
p22 = (pd.concat([BallTwentyTwo], keys = ['B22'], axis=1))
print(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15,p16,p17,p18,p19,p20,p21,p22)
```

Comment: There's a `df.T` to transpose the dataframe.

Comment: I've seen the df.T but i don't know where to put it in the code. I tried and it created more problems.

Comment: Check here for info on df.T - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html